# Faster RCNN, Why does conv's result can become the bbox_deltas?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, detection

[Here](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF/blob/master/lib/rpn_msr/proposal_layer_tf.py#L56) and [here](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF/blob/master/lib/rpn_msr/proposal_layer_tf.py#L95) are the code.

I'm confused that `rpn_bbox_pred` is just the result of convolution.

And `rpn_bbox_pred` is becoming the `bbox_deltas`.

I can not understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a `(3,2,36)` conv's result.

Note that:

```
36 = 4 * 9
```

So after reshape, each point of `(3,2)` have 9 proposal.

As the program shows:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[[1]*36,[2]*36],[[3]*36,[4]*36],[[5]*36,[6]*36]]
a = np.array(a)
print(a.reshape([-1,4]))
```

In the program, every `(3,2)` feature map is `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`.

The print result:

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [6 6 6 6]]
```